# setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility throws NPE (Support V7 rev 21.0.1)

Tags: java, android

Since I updated to the Android Support V7 revision 21 I get a NPE when calling setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility().

It seems that the progress inside an action bar is no longer supported this way.

What is the best alternative or workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`API-21` deprecated `ActionBar`.
The `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()` is not available anymore on `API-21`.

You should use `ToolBar` instead.

See: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score -2):

I add those lines in my `onCreate` to make it working :

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

For safety, put those codes before `setContentView`.

Comment: Is the first thing I tried but it crashes in my Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.4 =(

Comment: Its strange. Those code is working on my 4.4 (not nexus, though). Try my updated answer

Comment: Crashing on Nexus 5 API 21